# Build with gradle on windows 8.1 gives problems with desktop.ini

Tags: windows, cordova, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to build a cordova app I have build in Netbeans. It fails every time and I have been able to google the problems and solve them. Now I have come to a problem I cannot fix. I am building my app with gradle, with the command:
gradlew clean build

I get the following error:
(path to cordova project)\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\debug\xml\desktop.ini:1: error: Error parsing XML: syntax error

The problem is that windows automatically creates the desktop.ini file, when new folders are created, and this causes some problems.

I have tried to disable the creation of the desktop.ini file by adding this key to the registry:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"UseDesktopIniCache"=dword:00000000

It does not work and the desktop.ini file is still created.

Does anyone know how i can get around this? Can the creation of desktop.ini be disabled? Or can I get gradle to ignore desktop.ini?

Comment: I found out, that the issue comes, because I have my project in a Google Drive folder. It is Google Drive which creates those desktop.ini files

Answer (score 1):

I had to search the `desktop.ini` in the Application/src/main/res and Application/build folders and delete all to build the project. You may have to remove indexing of search results in windows to get the hidden `desktop.ini` files in the folder.

Comment: This is what I had to do too.

Comment: It worked for me. Not sure if there is a better approach.